# How can I get data from external API JSON file in ODOO

Tags: json, postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

[{"Id":"605a321e-7c10-49e4-9d34-ba03c4b34f69","Url":"","Type":"INBOUND_OUTBOUND",
"ClearCurrentData":true,"FillOutFormFields":true,"RequestProtocol":"HTTP_REQUEST",
"FileToSend":"NONE","SendDefaultData":false,"SendDetectionData":false,"ShowDialogMessage":false,"IsActive":false,"SendingTrigger":"MANUALLY","TCPSocketMethod":"","TriggerButtonName":"Get data"}]

**This is an External API Call JSON file how can i get the data in ODOO Any Solutions please ?**

**Mentioned Above code API JSON file**
i had only External JSON File,don't have a table name & Database name is it possible to get data in ODOO

Answer (score 0):

create a model for this data for example

```
class apiCall(models.Model):
    _name = 'apiCall.api'
    id = fields.Char(string='Id')
    url = fields.Char(string='url')
    @api.model
    def call_api(self):
    ### result of calling external api is "result"
    for line of self:
        id =  result[0].Id
        url = result[0].url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method on button click and access the json file. Below is the code for accessing json file:-

```
import json
def api_call(self):
   

   # Opening JSON file
   f = open('file_name.json',)

   # returns JSON object as 
   # a dictionary
   data = json.load(f)

   # Iterating through the json
   # list
   for i in self:
       print(i)

   # Closing file
   f.close()
```

Below is the button code which is applied in xml file:-

```
<button name="api_call" type="object" string="Call API" class="oe_highlight" />
```

by this way you can call the json file with external api in odoo.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module (my_custom_module), move your json file to its subdirectory static/src:

```py
import json
from odoo.modules.module import get_module_resource 

def call_api(self)
    json_filepath = get_module_resource('my_custom_module', 'static/src/', 'my_api_cred.json')
    with open(json_filepath) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```